# Printing issue when using GeoPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, geopy

I am completely new to Python so I appreciate that I maybe making a basic mistake somewhere. When I do the below, I get a "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" error after the print line. What am I doing wrong?

```
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

Comment: You're writing python2 code in a python3 intepreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are typing python 2 code in python 3. You need to have parentheses on the print statement.

Code:

```py
import geopy.distance

coords_1 = (52.2296756, 21.0122287)
coords_2 = (52.406374, 16.9251681)

print(geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).km)
```

Hope this helps!